# How to stop truncation in JavaScript number division

Tags: javascript

In Java we use the double or float data type to get results in decimal points. However how do i do this in Javascript? The current calculation i am doing is:

```
a1 += (a1 *  results[0][index]) / 100;
```

EDIT, My Apologises, There was a mistake on my side from using the wrong variables.

Comment: What error are you seeing? What value is in `a1` and `results[0][index]`?

Comment: If you think you're seeing something that looks like it's truncating your result, then you're probably misinterpreting something.

Answer (score 3):

All numbers in JavaScript are like Java "double" values. The general problem one encounters in JavaScript is how to do math as if they're *not* floating-point.

Thus in an expression like yours, if the numerator is not evenly divisible by 100 you'll get a value with a fractional part.  You can use "Math.round()" or "Math.floor()" to round or truncate the fraction, but you'll definitely get it.

Answer (score 2):

[`number.toFixed( \[numberOfDecimals\] )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

Comment: Well that's certainly a useful note, but the question seems to be about **not** truncating decimals.  Of course it may just be another case of a terribly-worded question :-)

Comment: @Pointy, yeah I was not sure if poster meant significant digits or the fact it does not keep the 0's. :) We cover both aspects. :)